# Google Admob MobileAds.Initialize() problem

Tags: android, admob

I just want to ask if there is anyone of you has encountered an error regarding implementing Google AdMob in your application. I have encountered this error and it seems that Google Admob is not initializing. What could be my problem?

Here is the error that i encountered regarding Google AdMob.

> android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (WebView.java:588)
>           at void android.webkit.WebView.(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int) (WebView.java:571)
>           at void android.webkit.WebView.(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (WebView.java:558)
>           at void android.webkit.WebView.(android.content.Conte     09-28 18:24:58.798 8854-8854/? I/WebViewFactory: Loading
>   com.android.chrome version 69.0.3497.100 (code 349710052)
>           09-28 18:24:58.823 8854-8854/? I/zygote64: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Landroid/webkit/TracingController;
>           at java.lang.Class java.lang.Class.classForName(java.lang.String, boolean,
>   java.lang.ClassLoader) (Class.java:-2)
>           at java.lang.Class java.lang.Class.forName(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.ClassLoader) (Class.java:453)
>           at java.lang.Class android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getWebViewProviderClass(java.lang.ClassLoader)
>   (WebViewFactory.java:129)
>           at java.lang.Class android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProviderClass()
>   (WebViewFactory.java:457)
>           at android.webkit.WebViewFactoryProvider android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider() (WebViewFactory.java:195)
>           at android.webkit.WebViewFactoryProvider android.webkit.WebView.getFactory() (WebView.java:2530)
>           at void android.webkit.WebView.ensureProviderCreated() (WebView.java:2525)
>           at void android.webkit.WebView.setOverScrollMode(int) (WebView.java:2590)
>           at void android.view.View.(android.content.Context) (View.java:4609)
>           at void android.view.View.(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (View.java:4758)
>           at void android.view.ViewGroup.(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (ViewGroup.java:597)
>           at void android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.(android.content.Context,
>   android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (AbsoluteLayout.java:55)
>           at void android.webkit.WebView.(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int, java.util.Map, boolean)
>   (WebView.java:643)
>           at void android.webkit.WebView.(android.content.Context, xt) (WebView.java:548)
>           at void com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.v.(com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.au,
>   com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.av, java.lang.String,
>   boolean, lv, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.client.p,
>   com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.csi.l,
>   com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.bm,
>   com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.v,
>   com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.clearcut.a)
>   (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@13280048@13.2.80
>   (040400-211705629):1)
>           at java.lang.Object com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.q.call() ((null):4)
>           at java.lang.Object com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.bp.a(java.util.concurrent.Callable)
>   (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@13280048@13.2.80
>   (040400-211705629):23)
>           at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.i com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.o.a(android.content.Context,
>   com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.av, java.lang.String,
>   boolean, boolean, lv,
>   com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.client.p,
>   com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.csi.l,
>   com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.bm,
>   com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.v,
>   com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.clearcut.a)
>   (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@13280048@13.2.80
>   (040400-211705629):5)
>           at void com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.q.(android.content.Context,
>   com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.client.p, lv)
>   (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@13280048@13.2.80
>   (040400-211705629):5)
>           at void com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.z.run() ((null):5)
>           at void com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.ad.execute(java.lang.Runnable)
>   (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@13280048@13.2.80
>   (040400-211705629):4)
>           at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.ao com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.y.a(lv)
>   (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@13280048@13.2.80
>   (040400-211705629):32)
>           at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.ak com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.y.a()
>   (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@13280048@13.2.80
>   (040400-211705629):17)
>           at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.x com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.function.b.b(java.lang.Object)
>   (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@13280048@13.2.80
>   (040400-211705629):9)
>           at void com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.ab.a(android.content.Context,
>   com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.client.p, boolean,
>   com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.state.e, java.lang.String,
>   java.lang.String, java.lang.Runnable)
>   (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@13280048@13.2.80
>   (040400-211705629):32)
>           at void com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.ab.a(android.content.Context,
>   com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.client.p, java.lang.String,
>   java.lang.Runnable)
>   (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@13280048@13.2.80
>   (040400-211705629):4)
>           at void com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.aw.a(java.lang.String, wd)
>   (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@13280048@13.2.80
>   (040400-211705629):52)
>           at boolean com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.bc.a(int,
>   android.os.Parcel, android.os.Parcel)
>   (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@13280048@13.2.80
>   (040400-211705629):42)
>           at boolean na.onTransact(int, android.os.Parcel, android.os.Parcel, int)
>   (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@13280048@13.2.80
>   (040400-211705629):10)
>           at boolean android.os.Binder.transact(int, android.os.Parcel, android.os.Parcel, int) (Binder.java:644)
>           at void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzej.transactAndReadExceptionReturnVoid(int,
>   android.os.Parcel) ((null):-1)
>           at void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzll.zza(java.lang.String,
>   com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper) ((null):-1)
>           at void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzmb.zza(android.content.Context,
>   java.lang.String, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzmd)
>   ((null):-1)
>           at void com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds.initialize(android.content.Context,
>   java.lang.String, com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds$Settings)
>   ((null):-1)
>           at void com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds.initialize(android.content.Context,
>   java.lang.String) ((null):-1)
>           at void abaka.cdu.com.ph.infocenter.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
>   (MainActivity.java:15)
>           at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle, android.os.PersistableBundle) (Activity.java:7041)
>           at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:7032)
>           at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity,
>   android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1231)
>           at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord,
>   android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2864)
>           at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord,
>   android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2989)
>           at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(android.app.ActivityThread,
>   android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord,
>   android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
>           at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message)
>   (ActivityThread.java:1688)
>           at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:106)
>           at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:164)
>           at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6753)
>           at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[])
>   (Method.java:-2)
>           at void com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run()
>   (RuntimeInit.java:482)
>           at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[])
>   (ZygoteInit.java:807)
>           Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.webkit.TracingController" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.android.chrome-J2AR7AxH-H4feR9KfsbSkw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.android.chrome-J2AR7AxH-H4feR9KfsbSkw==/lib/arm64,
>   /data/app/com.android.chrome-J2AR7AxH-H4feR9KfsbSkw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a,
>   /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
>           at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String)
>   (BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
>           at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean)
>   (ClassLoader.java:379)
>           at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String)
>   (ClassLoader.java:312)
>           at java.lang.Class java.lang.Class.classForName(java.lang.String, boolean,
>   java.lang.ClassLoader) (Class.java:-2)
>           at java.lang.Class java.lang.Class.forName(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.ClassLoader) (Class.java:453)
>           at java.lang.Class android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getWebViewProviderClass(java.lang.ClassLoader)
>   (WebViewFactory.java:129)
>           at java.lang.Class android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProviderClass()
>   (WebViewFactory.java:457)
>           at android.webkit.WebViewFactoryProvider android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider() (WebViewFactory.java:195)
>           at android.webkit.WebViewFactoryProvider android.webkit.WebView.getFactory() (WebView.java:2530)
>           at void android.webkit.WebView.ensureProviderCreated() (WebView.java:2525)
>           at void android.webkit.WebView.setOverScrollMode(int) (WebView.java:2590)
>           at void android.view.View.(android.content.Context) (View.java:4609)
>           at void android.view.View.(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (View.java:4758)
>           at void android.view.ViewGroup.(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (ViewGroup.java:597)
>           at void android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.(android.content.Context,
>   android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (AbsoluteLayout.java:55)
>           at void android.webkit.WebView.(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int, java.util.Map, boolean)
>   (WebView.java:643)
>           at void android.webkit.WebView.(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (WebView.java:588)
>           at void android.webkit.WebView.(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int) (WebView.java:571)
>           at void android.webkit.WebView.(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (WebView.java:558)
>           at void android.webkit.WebView.(android.content.Context) (WebView.java:548)
>           at void com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.v.(com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.au,
>   com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.av, java.lang.String,
>   boolean, lv, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.client.p,
>   com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.csi.l,
>   com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.bm,
>   com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.v,
>   com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.clearcut.a)
>   (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@13280048@13.2.80
>   (040400-211705629):1)
>           at java.lang.Object com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.q.call() ((null):4)
>           at java.lang.Object com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.bp.a(java.util.concurrent.Callable)
>   (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@13280048@13.2.80
>   (040400-211705629):23)
>           at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.i com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.o.a(android.content.Context,
>   com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.av, java.lang.String,
>   boolean, boolean, lv,
>   com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.client.p,
>   com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.csi.l,
>   com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.bm,
>   com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.v,
>   com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.clearcut.a)
>   (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@13280048@13.2.80
>   (040400-211705629):5)
>           at void com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.q.(android.content.Context,
>   com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.client.p, lv)
>   (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@13280048@13.2.80
>   (040400-211705629):5)
>           at void com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.z.run() ((null):5)

Comment: Please share your code also

Comment: I experience the same issue, it looks like one of the ad networks are using a `TracingController`, this was only added in api 28, meaning that if you run your application on a device running <28, you will experience this. I'm still trying to resolve this, when I do I will let you know.

Comment: Facing the same issue after updating targetAPI level. @ClassA were you able to find a resolution?

Comment: @AlexVPerl you can just ignore it, it doesn't cause the application to crash.

Comment: Try uninstalling the app manually and re-install again. It has worked for me.

Comment: Can confirm does not cause any visible issues yet. Ads still load fine. Reinstalling the app did not resolve this warning. Seems like some internal AdMob stuff..